Why is this simple swift nested for loop is so slow
I have a very basic nested for loop iterates over a 80K long string. This loop at most must take 2-3 miliseconds but it takes 10 seconds on my iphone. This is an inexplicable time for a smart phone. Why could this be happening? Here is the code.
let cyph_1 : [Character] = my_array1 // 65 characters
let cyph_2 : [Character] = my_array2 // 65 characters
var temp_2 = ""
var temp_1 = "80K long string, not that long"
for k in 0 ..< temp_1.count
{
    var exists = false
    let some_char = temp_1_characters[k]
    for m in 0 ..< cyph_2.count
    {
        if (cyph_2[m] == some_char)
        {
            temp_2.append(cyph_1[m])
            exists = true
            break
        }
    }
    if (!exists)
    {
        temp_2 += "\(some_char)"
    }
}
temp_1 = temp_2


This is a very inefficient way of implemententing a transposition cipher. Start by converting cyph_1 and cyph_2 to a dictionary of [Character:Character]

Still, it shouldn't take 10 seconds to run. The similar code on an android device runs under milliseconds.

There may be other factors at work. You need to show a [mcve]

I can't exactly show more than that but your dictionary solution was correct. For some reason, reading from 2 arrays were horribly slow. Answer the question please and i will accept your answer. Thanks.

I just implemented your code and it took around 0.7 seconds to execute on an iPhone 13 Pro, so there was something else going on.  Rob's dictionary implantation took about 0.00002 seconds

There are several potential performance issues here:

“Debug” builds are unoptimized and have lots of safety checks, which slows it down. Thus, loops will be much slower than they would be in optimized “release” builds. To select debug vs. release, choose “Edit Scheme…” and check your scheme’s “Run” settings:


You are looping within a loop, which is inefficient. Build a dictionary and you will enjoy O(1) performance for each character substitution.

Building a string by appending characters one at a time is inefficient, resulting in the string buffer being resized multiple times. We would often reserveCapacity, to reduce this effect. With small strings, this effect is immaterial, but with longer strings, it might have an observable impact on performance.


E.g., my simple approach:
class Cypher {
    private let encodeKey: [Character: Character]
    private let decodeKey: [Character: Character]
    
    init(cyph1: [Character], cyph2: [Character]) {
        encodeKey = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(cyph1, cyph2))
        decodeKey = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(cyph2, cyph1))
    }
    
    func encode(_ input: String) -> String {
        String(input.compactMap { encodeKey[$0] })
    }
    
    func decode(_ input: String) -> String {
        String(input.compactMap { decodeKey[$0] })
    }
}

Or, if you really wanted to use a for loop:
class Cypher {
    private let encodeKey: [Character: Character]
    private let decodeKey: [Character: Character]
    
    init(cyph1: [Character], cyph2: [Character]) {
        encodeKey = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(cyph1, cyph2))
        decodeKey = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(cyph2, cyph1))
    }
    
    func encode(_ input: String) -> String {
        var output = ""
        output.reserveCapacity(input.count)
        
        for character in input {
            if let encodedCharacter = encodeKey[character] {
                output.append(encodedCharacter)
            }
        }
    
        return output
    }
    
    func decode(_ input: String) -> String {
        var output = ""
        output.reserveCapacity(input.count)
        
        for character in input {
            if let decodedCharacter = decodeKey[character] {
                output.append(decodedCharacter)
            }
        }
    
        return output
    }
}

Just to explain the building of these [Character: Character] dictionaries: The uniqueKeysWithValues initializer of Dictionary expects an array of tuples of keys and values. And the zip will build those arrays of tuples by marrying respective elements into tuples from the two sequences, cyph1 and cyph2.
